# Print Log Entry (textPayload) in Logging Policy Alert sent to Slack etc

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

In GCP We have a Policy set to alert when there is a heartbeat failure to one of our "Spokes"

In GCP logging we used a basic log query string match for "Spoke is not ready ... heartbeat for spoke[100]" that matches for everything prior to the spoke number as that is dynamic.

I would like to find a way to be able to print the exact log entry within the "Policy Documentation" field so that it shows the actual spoke that went down (or the full log entry of textPayload, as both contain the spoke ID)

We tried with placing $(textPayload) in the field, but it did not work.

Going through the logging docs, and I can't see to find anything that can be used. Is something like this possible or will it require some more complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they don't provide it, but here's a [list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#doc-vars) of available variables for the documentation, and textPayload is just not there :(

Answer (score 0):

Lumaks already shared [this link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#doc-vars). Notice the line "log.extracted_label.*KEY*" – you need to define a label extractor KEY for the textPayload, then you can reference it in the documentation text.

Since I couldn't find a way to define a label extractor within the web interface, I downloaded my alert policy as JSON, edited that file and then updated the policy via gcloud cli:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to [Monitoring > Alerting > Policies](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies) and select your policy. At the top there is a button to download the policy definition as JSON.
2. Add your labelExtractors within the key "conditionMatchedLog". I have inserted mine below "filter":

   ```
    {
        "name": "projects/YOUR-PROJECT/alertPolicies/POLICY-ID",
        "displayName": "My Slack Alerts",
        "documentation": {
            "content": "Severity: ${log.extracted_label.severity}  \nText: ${log.extracted_label.text_payload}",
            "mimeType": "text/markdown"
        },
        "userLabels": {},
        "conditions": [
            {
                "name": "projects/YOUR-PROJECT/alertPolicies/POLICY-ID/conditions/CONDITION-ID",
                "displayName": "Log match condition",
                "conditionMatchedLog": {
                    "filter": "resource.type=\"cloud_function\"\nseverity=(NOTICE OR WARNING OR ERROR OR CRITICAL OR ALERT OR EMERGENCY)",
                    "labelExtractors": {
                        "text_payload": "EXTRACT(textPayload)",
                        "severity": "EXTRACT(severity)"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        …
    }
   ```

   What is entered here inside the "EXTRACT(...)" can be found as a key when you expand a log entry in the Cloud Console. This way it should be possible to extract other values that you see there.

   Notice that I also updated the `documentation.content` here, to use the extracted labels.
3. Update your policy using gcloud cli tool:

   ```
    gcloud --project YOUR-PROJECT alpha monitoring policies update POLICY-ID --policy-from-file="your-updated-file.json"
   ```

After also wondering for months how to output the textPayload, I used [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts#policy_specifics) general description of how to edit labelExtractors in JSON and create a policy via gcloud cli to come up with this idea. I just tried it and had some luck.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Google now have a UI options for doing this

- Edit the Policy Alert Details
- In "Choose logs to include in the alert" section
- "Extract log labels (Optional)"

I entered

- Display Name: Message
- Log Field Name: textPayload
- Regular Expression: (.*)

This produced

```
    "labelExtractors": {
      "Message": "REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, \"(.*)\")"
    }
```

Note: this uses the REGEXP_EXTRACT function so there are full regex capabilities